# How and where is state preserved between function calls

Tags: f2py

I'm investigating a fortran routine wrapped by f2py. I've observed that the function is not pure -- the values that it returns are based not only on it's current arguments but also previous function calls. My questions are:

1. How could this happen?
2. Is it possible, and how to extract the state present before I call the function?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Let me know if you need help reproducing this issue. I've looked at the sources and I cannot understand what is happening.

Comment: @xaav Links get stale. Please post the relevant code as part of the question.

Comment: The question implies that the "unpure" function is not on the python side, but the fortran one - can we see that code? Or should the question be clarified?

Comment: I am trying to reduce the test case to something manageable. The problem is that because it isn't a pure function, that's become difficult to accomplish. I was hoping that someone with knowledge of f2py could respond with a general answer about where such state could be present.

Comment: Do you think I should post the C wrapper and the fortran routine as well?

Comment: I'm getting the same output btw calls to this python script and I don't see the precise location of the problem or any avidence of it thus far? Can you elaborate on how do you see that the function is state dependent? And yes, Fortran routine that you are calling would be helpful.

Comment: The function can be shown to be state-dependent by placing `calls = calls[:3] + [calls[-1]]` before `for call in calls`. This eliminates some, but not the last function call, yet changes the result.

Comment: It may take a bit to extract and isolate the functions.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a `SAVE` statement in the Fortran routine, there can be state that is only accessible from Fortran, and cannot be accessed from Python or (easily) from C. The simplest way to capture this state is (probably) to simple add print statements to show the variable values.